# ASP.Net and Ajax Server code behind constant re-create

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am writing a single ASP Form that dynamically changes Div boxes that are visible from mouse clicks on buttons and when text in textboxes is changed in an Ajax container. The problem i have is in the Page_Load function i create all the objects (text boxes, radio buttons, buttons, etc) dynamically from a .csv file template sitting on the asp hosting server. Everytime a postback happens, even within the Ajax window, the Page_Load function is called again and the .csv file is re-read, and all objects are re-created.

I have tried Checking for IsPostback before re-creating any objects but the objects are then nullified as they have never been created. The page is as a completely new page every single time.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Page_PreInit event rather than Page_Load to re-create/manipulate your dynamic controls:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // create controls here
}
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: Just tried PreInit and the function is also fired every change the same as Page_Load, Although the linked page just added is proving useful. Let me see what i can pull out of it.

Comment: This Answer lead me to find the answer i needed. I had to re-check the values in the fields after regeneration. After putting the construction of the page into PreInit i could work out what needed to be done before anything else happened.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a dynamic control, you must accept the responsibility of 
re-creating the control upon each postback.
You should create the control in the Page_Init event for every page 
request whether it's a postback or not. If you create your controls in the Page_Init event then following that the 
user entered values should automatically be filled in upon each postback so 
you can acces them.